# how to create a dictionary of list of dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I need to create a dictionary of list of dictionaries or if there is any other way of achieving the below requirement:

i have a set of keys let say
    keys = [1,2,3,4,5] (dont consider this as list but i am just showing i have let say 5 keys)

for each key i will have a set of key value pair so something lime below:

```
d = {
    1:{
        {'one': 'test', 'two': 'new', 'three': 'dummy'}
        {'one': 'testtest', 'two': 'newnew', 'three': 'dummyextra'}
        {'one': 'newvalue', 'two': 'newvalue2', 'three': 'newvalue4'}
    }
    2:{
        {'one': 'test1', 'two': 'new1', 'three': 'dummy1'}
        {'one': 'testtest2', 'two': 'newnew2', 'three': 'dummyextra2'}
        {'one': 'newvalue3', 'two': 'newvalue23', 'three': 'newvalue43'}
    }
    1:{
        {'one': 'test', 'two': 'new', 'three': 'dummy'}
        {'one': 'testtest', 'two': 'newnew', 'three': 'dummyextra'}
        {'one': 'newvalue', 'two': 'newvalue2', 'three': 'newvalue4'}
    }

}
```

All the inner and outer dictionaries will be forming through loops.

If because of unique key the above is not possible than what will be the alternate solution to get the data in above format (list of dictionaries or dictionary of lists or anything else?).

With above my main agenda is i will have a unique tag that will be the key of outer dictionary and using that tag i will be creating one HTML header, 
under that header i will b populating the data i.e. multiple links and that internal data has to come from inner dictionary from the example.

So in this example i have an html page with header title 1 and under this header i will have 3 links that wil come from inner dictionary.

Than i will have header 2 and again 3 links under it and so on.

Kindly help me to achieve this.

Thanks,

Comment: Look into `defaultdict()`.

Comment: Hi Ankur, Please check the syntax of your dictionary. Did you mean the values of your outer dictionary to be lists and not dicts? Also you need to have commas between elements of a list or a dict. :)

Comment: @Srini: I tried to achieve this by making list also but somehow its not giving me expected result, so i am trying with dictionary inside dictionary

Comment: Also what exactly the problem is unclear, what HTML are you trying to populate? What error did you encounter when you attempted to use a list? Providing all these details will enable people looking at the q to answer you better :). Also FYI you are overwriting the key `1` in your dict

Answer (score 0):

You just have to represent lists with `[]` not `{}` and don't forget the commas (`,`) to separate the elements:

```
d = {
    1:[
        {'one': 'test', 'two': 'new', 'three': 'dummy'},
        {'one': 'testtest', 'two': 'newnew', 'three': 'dummyextra'},
        {'one': 'newvalue', 'two': 'newvalue2', 'three': 'newvalue4'}
    ],
    2:[
        {'one': 'test1', 'two': 'new1', 'three': 'dummy1'},
        {'one': 'testtest2', 'two': 'newnew2', 'three': 'dummyextra2'},
        {'one': 'newvalue3', 'two': 'newvalue23', 'three': 'newvalue43'}
    ],
    3:[
        {'one': 'test', 'two': 'new', 'three': 'dummy'},
        {'one': 'testtest', 'two': 'newnew', 'three': 'dummyextra'},
        {'one': 'newvalue', 'two': 'newvalue2', 'three': 'newvalue4'}
    ]

}
```

Comment: `,` is a comma. Not a colon, which is `:`

Comment: You can't have 2 keys the same.

Comment: @PeterWood you can technically, the second definition would just overwrite the first

Comment: @Srini You can have duplicate keys in a dictionary literal, but not in a dictionary actual (c:

Answer (score 0):

Try to guess something similar to your input (`dlist`) just to how how to build a dict using a list as a default value and appending data:

```
dlist = [[2, {'two': 'two1'}], [1, {'one': 'one1'}], [1, {'one': 'one2'}], [2, {'two': 'two2'}] ]

res = {}
for item in dlist:
    res.setdefault(item[0], list()).append(item[1])

print(res)
#=> {1: [{'one': 'one1'}, {'one': 'one2'}], 2: [{'two': 'two1'}, {'two': 'two2'}]}
```